# The term for a person who "re-joins" an organisation

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, formality, epithet-requests

I'm looking for a term (or terms) to describe a person who leaves a group (or organisation), and then later re-joins.

Something like a *"re-joiner"* perhaps?

For example, a *"leaver"* is someone who leaves or has left, and an *"onboarder"* or *"inductee"* may describe a new-starter.  My language is British English, but it doesn't really matter.

Example sentence as per the comments, *"Mr ABC is a _____; he left in February but returned back in May".*  Or, the actual usage in my own field:

> Person A: "Is he a new starter or a leaver?"
>
> Person B: "No, he's a _____; he left, then came back two months later"

Comment: As the `single-word-requests` tag's description requests, please add an example sentence.

Comment: [returnee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/returnee) works in many contexts.

Comment: Example sentence added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Fumblefingers, *returnee* may work. It certainly fits your context.

M-W:

> [*returnee*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/returnee):
>   someone who returns to a place or activity

Your example:

> Person A: "Is he a new starter or a leaver?"
>
> Person B: "No, he's a *returnee*; he left, then came back two months
>   later."

You could also consider *comebacker* (or *come-backer* or *come backer*). It might work for your purposes. I can imagine describing so and so as a *comebacker*.

Comment: That fits perfectly.  A word I never knew existed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a

> [readmitted](http://www.capitalcc.edu/congratulations/welcome-readmitted-students/)

or a

> [readmitee](https://books.google.ca/books?id=lChACgAAQBAJ&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=readmittee&source=bl&ots=3jOX-BqTmL&sig=J4ZCzbiN0ddbJ4oNu9qbtvIv5vo&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRy6P8gcLQAhUCw4MKHXorBLIQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=readmittee&f=false) on a legal context.

Comment: Okay thanks.  What is that term when applied to the person?  For example, *he's a "readmittee"*?

Comment: I updated the answer to add readmitee as an alternative for a legal context.

Comment: Nice, thank you.  Are there any other alternatives that are slightly less *formal*?  This is a good word though; I've never heard of it before...

Comment: Then you are probably stuck with the down voted "prodigal son". At least on the three languages I'm very familiar with, anybody would get the idea on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

***[Reentrant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/re-entrant)***

I had seen it used to describe reentering college students.  But the Oxford Dictionary says

> 2 A person who has re-entered something, especially the labor force.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably tend to [returner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/returner), but I'd also suggest that there's no one specific term to describe the situation.